# Uncaught TypeError on self calling function in CHROME

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console, syntax-error

I'm getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function " with this at the end of my javascript file:

```
(function(){Δ.update.jsStatusUpdate(1);})();
```

and yes, the function `Δ.update.jsStatusUpdate` is defined before it is called.

Comment: What's the definition of `Δ.update.jsStatusUpdate`? Does it try to call any other functions that might not be defined?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski no, it just updates a variable that is defined already.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski it even has the error if I use a browser defined function such as `alert`.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski ah hah! I figured out the issue!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is embarrassing, but JSHint didn't even catch it.

The issue was that a previous function definition didn't have a semicolon at the end! DOH!!!

Comment: I guess this is a very common thing to miss. Took me quite a while to figure it out.